# Редирект при регистрации

Tags: php

Написал регистрацию на сайте, но при клике войти, переходит на страницу auth.php, но она пустая. Может кто-нибудь помочь разобраться?
Файл auth.php

```
<?php
    session_start();


    require_once("dbconnect.php");
    $_SESSION["error_messages"] = '';
    $_SESSION["success_messages"] = '';

function generateCode($length=6) {

    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHI JKLMNOPRQSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

    $code = "";

    $clen = strlen($chars) - 1;  
    while (strlen($code) < $length) {

            $code .= $chars[mt_rand(0,$clen)];  
    }

    return $code;
}


    if(isset($_POST["btn_submit_auth"]) && !empty($_POST["btn_submit_auth"])){
        if(isset($_POST["captcha"])){
            $captcha = trim($_POST["captcha"]);
                if(!empty($captcha)){
                    if(($_SESSION["rand"] != $captcha) && ($_SESSION["rand"] != "")){
                    $error_message = "<p class='mesage_error'><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Вы ввели неправильную капчу </p>";
                    $_SESSION["error_messages"] = $error_message;
                    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                    header("Location: ".$address_site."form_auth.php");
                    exit();
                }
            }else{

                $error_message = "<p class='mesage_error'><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Поле для ввода капчи не должна быть пустой. </p>";
                $_SESSION["error_messages"] = $error_message;
                header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                header("Location: ".$address_site."form_auth.php");

                //Останавливаем скрипт
                exit();
            }

            //(2) Место для обработки почтового адреса
            if(isset($_POST["email"])){
                $email = trim($_POST["email"]);

                if(!empty($email)){
                    $email = htmlspecialchars($email, ENT_QUOTES);
                    $reg_email = "/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\._-]*[a-z0-9]*@([a-z0-9]+([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]+/i";
                    if( !preg_match($reg_email, $email)){
                        $_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Вы ввели неправильный email</p>";

                        //Возвращаем пользователя на страницу авторизации
                        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                        header("Location: ".$address_site."form_auth.php");

                        //Останавливаем скрипт
                        exit();
                    }

                }else{

                    $_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Поле для ввода почтового адреса(email) не должна быть пустой.</p>";


                    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                    header("Location: ".$address_site."form_register.php");


                    exit();
                }


            }else{
                // Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
                $_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Отсутствует поле для ввода Email</p>";

                //Возвращаем пользователя на страницу авторизации
                header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                header("Location: ".$address_site."form_auth.php");

                //Останавливаем скрипт
                exit();
            }


             //(3) Место для обработки пароля
            if(isset($_POST["password"])){

                //Обрезаем пробелы с начала и с конца строки
                $password = trim($_POST["password"]);

                if(!empty($password)){
                    $password = htmlspecialchars($password, ENT_QUOTES);

                    //Шифруем пароль
                    $password = md5($password."top_secret");
                }else{
                    // Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
                    $_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Укажите Ваш пароль</p>";

                    //Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
                    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                    header("Location: ".$address_site."form_auth.php");

                    //Останавливаем скрипт
                    exit();
                }

            }else{
                // Сохраняем в сессию сообщение об ошибке. 
                $_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Отсутствует поле для ввода пароля</p>";

                //Возвращаем пользователя на страницу регистрации
                header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                header("Location: ".$address_site."form_auth.php");

                //Останавливаем скрипт
                exit();
            }

            $result_query_select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password = '".$password."'");

            if(!$result_query_select){
                $_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Ошибка запроса на выборке пользователя из БД</p>";


                header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                header("Location: ".$address_site."form_auth.php");
              exit();
            }else{

                //Проверяем, если в базе нет пользователя с такими данными, то выводим сообщение об ошибке
                if($result_query_select->num_rows == 1){
                        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='$email'");
                          $hash = md5(generateCode(10));
                          $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                          $mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET user_hash='".$hash."' WHERE email='".$row['email']."'");
setcookie("hash", $hash, time()-60*60*24);
setcookie("id", $row['id'], time()-60*60*24);
                            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                            $_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >вы вошли</p>";
                            $ResHash = $mysqli->query("SELECT `user_hash` FROM `userы` WHERE email='$email'");
                            $ArrayHash = $ResHash->fetch_assoc();
                           setcookie("id", $row['id'], time()+60*60*24);
                            setcookie("hash", $ArrayHash['user_hash'], time()+60*60*24);
                            //Возвращаем пользователя на главную страницу
                            header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                            header("Location: ".$address_site."index.php");


                            exit();


                    }

                else{


                    $_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error' >Неправильный логин и/или пароль</p>";
                    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                    header("Location: ".$address_site."form_auth.php");

                    exit();
                }
            }

        }else{
            exit("<p><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Отсутствует проверочный код, то есть код капчи. Вы можете перейти на <a href=".$address_site."> главную страницу </a>.</p>");
        }

    }else{
        exit("<p><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Вы зашли на эту страницу напрямую, поэтому нет данных для обработки. Вы можете перейти на <a href=".$address_site."> главную страницу </a>.</p>");
    }
```

Comment: Так после регистрации  переход на корень сайта `header("Location: /");`

Comment: вам реально удобнее писать все одной портянкой кода что ли? разбейте вы его на функции `checkCaptcha`, `checkPassword`, `redirect()` и  т.п. второй раз постите, а никакой структуры кода не появилось.